# Retain unmatched strings with regmatches (R)

Tags: regex, r, excel, expression

**Background Problem:**

Currently we have a list of item descriptions (1278 obs), some of which have Product Codes in them. E.g ("REF VLOC0004 V LOC 3/0 15CM SUTURE DEVICE"), the code would be VLOC0004.

I have this stored as an excel file, and I would like a column next to the description column with the item codes filled in next to each description.

**Current Work done:**

I have managed to load the data into R and am able to write my own patterns for regular expressions (I may revist this if I feel I am not up to the task of picking up a few strings of codes). E.g R Code below.

```
# Pattern
p=("([A-Z]*[0-9]{4,}[A-Z]*)|([0-9]+[:punct:][0-9]+)|([0-9]+[:punct:][0-9]+[:punct:][0-9]+)")
# Match data from regexpr()
m<-regexpr(p,EGIA$LGY_DHB_ITEM_DESCRIPTION)
```

**The Problem:**

When I run regmatches to extract the pattern above, it only extracts found matches and ignores descriptions with no codes in them. The result is it creates a vector of only 608 length. If I were to use this column next to my item descriptions, the codes wouldn't line up with the descriptions. What I need is this vector to somehow give a blank spot where the item code isn't found, so that this extract vector is the same length of the item description.

I played around with the inverse command but it did no good. Any help on this would be appreciated, I have looked around numerous tutorials on regular expressions and on this site but am overwhelmed with information, none of which seems relevant.

Comment: Can you provide an output result?

Comment: I tried to do an illustration but im relatively new here and couldn't get the text to line up with the columns etc. Is there a way I can link a screenshot of an excel example?

Comment: Seems I missed this duplicate question, sorry about that. A side note, I wanted to find numbers separated by a "-". I used this symbol and the pattern was picked up fine. I then replaced it by [:punct;] and now it won't find it. I was hoping to use  [:punct;] to pick up codes with different punctuation in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Could do a simple combination of `str_detect` + `ifelse`. Sure there is many other ways of doing this.

```
library(stringr)
str <- c("ab", "bc", "cd")
yes <- str_detect(str, "c")
ifelse(yes==T, "c", NA)
#NA  "c" "c"
```

Comment: The code does not change the str content. This is how we can do it. `str<-ifelse(yes==T, "c", NA)`